# Próximo valor em uma ordem aleatória de números

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um botão NEXT, esse Next irá mostrar o próximo conteúdo, sendo que todos esses conteúdos estão armazenados no banco de dados e todos possuem um ID.

Tudo seria muito simples se os ID fossem sequenciais tipo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, mas não é... E é ai que estou com o problema...

Na filtragem de dados (COMO UMA CATEGORIA), os ID deixam de ser sequencias tipo 1 3 4 7.

Estou usando PDO, eu filtro os IDs daquela categoria em questão, porém não consigo criar o botão NEXT.

Comment: Seria um ORDER BY RAND() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se os IDs estiverem em ordem crescente (1, 4, 37, 1278, 12888):

```
SELECT id FROM artigos WHERE id > (PONHA O ID ATUAL AQUI) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

e para obter o anterior:

```
SELECT id FROM artigos WHERE id < (PONHA O ID ATUAL AQUI) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Aplicando ao PDO, incluindo o filtro de categoria:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id FROM artigos WHERE id > ? AND categoria = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $idAtual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $codCategoria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$nextId = $result['id'];
```

> Esta solução **também funciona** se os `id`s não estiverem em ordem numérica, basta trocar o `id` do WHERE e do ORDER pelo campo desejado na ordenação, desde que sejam únicos.

Exemplo

```
SELECT id FROM artigos WHERE titulo > (PONHA O titulo ATUAL AQUI) LIMIT 1 ORDER BY titulo
```

Comment: Muito obrigado... Resolveu meu problema...

Comment: no exemplo que você me deu voce mostrou o modo que funcionaria se os ID's  estiverem em ordem crescente (1, 4, 37, 1278, 12888), para isso era só usar o sinal '>'. Supondo que os id's não estejam ordenados de forma crescente tipo: (1 4 20 10 15) como eu posso fazer para mesmo assim pular para a próxima postagem?

Comment: Só seguir o ultimo exemplo (ultima linha da resposta), e ordenar por qualquer outro campo sem ser o ID. (no exemplo usei titulo, mas você pode usar o campo que quiser).